# Error while running odoo in mac

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to install odoo in mac OS. I have installed all necessary requirements by referring a video on youtube and finally I tried to run server but I am getting an error like this:

> ```
> lalits-MacBook-Pro:odoo lalitpatidar$ ./odoo-bin
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./odoo-bin", line 5, in 
>     __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace('odoo.addons')
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1926, in declare_namespace
>     declare_namespace(parent)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1942, in declare_namespace
>     _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1912, in _handle_ns
>     loader.load_module(packageName); module.__path__ = path
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pkgutil.py", line 246, in load_module
>     mod = imp.load_module(fullname, self.file, self.filename, self.etc)
>   File "/Users/lalitpatidar/Desktop/v10/odoo/odoo/__init__.py", line 60, in 
>     import modules
>   File "/Users/lalitpatidar/Desktop/v10/odoo/odoo/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in 
>     from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry
>   File "/Users/lalitpatidar/Desktop/v10/odoo/odoo/modules/graph.py", line 13, in 
>     import odoo.osv as osv
>   File "/Users/lalitpatidar/Desktop/v10/odoo/odoo/osv/__init__.py", line 4, in 
>     import osv
>   File "/Users/lalitpatidar/Desktop/v10/odoo/odoo/osv/osv.py", line 4, in 
>     from ..exceptions import except_orm
>   File "/Users/lalitpatidar/Desktop/v10/odoo/odoo/exceptions.py", line 15, in 
>     from tools.func import frame_codeinfo
>   File "/Users/lalitpatidar/Desktop/v10/odoo/odoo/tools/__init__.py", line 8, in 
>     from misc import *
>   File "/Users/lalitpatidar/Desktop/v10/odoo/odoo/tools/misc.py", line 16, in 
>     import passlib.utils
> ImportError: No module named passlib.utils
> ```

I am new in odoo and stackoverflow as well so please avoid my little mistake if any.

Comment: (Welcome to posting on SO!) Avoiding someone else's mistakes sounds wise, if hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can install passlib module using pip

**sudo pip install passlib**

Comment: Thanks to giving answer....still some libraries are need to install and i installed them one by one as it was showing as error but some libraries are not found like pychart etc. so its still not running and giving error

Comment: Did you try to installing them by pip install -r requirements.txt? This file should be found on odoo's core.

Comment: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 2 in /private/var/folders/lq/hy2clcv55wl5b25m809g9cs40000gn/T/pip-build-gPdkZh/suds-jurko/................This line is showing when i fire 'pip install -r requirements.txt' command after some processing